# How to use dexdump in ubuntu

Tags: android, dex

I was trying to use on dex tools to look on high level overview of classes and methods on android dex file (classes.dex)
But i found the following error when i use dexdump

> > dexdump -d classes.dex | less

dexdump: command not found

Can someone help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

to invoke it directly you need to have the full qualified path to `PATH` and it is not. On my machine is located under `build-tools/{version}`. E.g.

```
./build-tools/19.0.1/dexdump
./build-tools/19.1.0/dexdump
./build-tools/20.0.0/dexdump
./build-tools/21.0.2/dexdump
./build-tools/21.1.1/dexdump
./build-tools/21.1.2/dexdump
./build-tools/22.0.1/dexdump
./build-tools/23.0.1/dexdump
./build-tools/23.0.2/dexdump
```

what you can do is to `cd` in your `sdk` directory and look for it

```
find . -name dexdump
```

and then prepend the relative path to the command, like `build-tools/19.0.1/dexdump`, or use the full qualified path like `/path/to/sdk/build-tools/19.0.1/dexdump`

or in your case

```
/path/to/sdk/build-tools/19.0.1/dexdump -d classes.dex | less
```

Comment: Thanks. But that was what I did. I just run the command being in the directory where dexdump resides.    
No command 'dexdump' found, did you mean:
Command 'hexdump' from package 'bsdmainutils' (main)
 Command 'devdump' from package 'genisoimage' (main)
 Command 'derdump' from package 'libnss3-tools' (main)
 dexdump: command not found
.......is what I got. @Blackbelt

Comment: if you are inside the same directory you have to use `./dexdump` . Please note `./` before `dexdump`